# Get Select Array Value on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get Select Element Array value using javascript but i cant get i get all other element value like text etc but cant get select array value.

Select element in My **Html** code

```
<select name="abc[]"></select>
<select name="abc[]"></select>
```

and **Javascript** Code for get Select Value

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='abc[]']")
```

but cant get its value, Help me out of this

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll("select[name='abc[]']")`.

Comment: and how to get text of that selected option?

Answer (score 1):

First: use `select`, not `input` in your [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). Here's a snippet to find the value and text of the selected option:

```js
const selectedOption = document.querySelector(`select[name='abc[]'] > option:checked`);
console.log(`Value: ${selectedOption.value}, Text: ${selectedOption.textContent}`);
```

```html
<select name="abc[]">
  <option value="1">text 1</option>
  <option value="2">text 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>text 3</option>
  <option value="4">text 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :   [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/phiphophe/c7a3gdtn/1/

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("select[name='abc[]']");

for(var select of matches){
console.log(select.value);
}
```